# How to add text below IconButton on TopAppBar?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to put some text below IconButton, but I just can't find a way. Instead it just gets beside the IconButton
[TopAppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgfWO.jpg)

```
 Column {
        TopAppBar(
                modifier = modifier,
                elevation = 0.dp,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Jetpack Compose")
                },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, tint = Red)
                    }
                    Text(text = "Add")
                }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`TopAppBar` action is aligned inside the `Row`, So If you add any component inside that it will grow horizontally, So you can add your text and button inside `IconButton` because the icon is just a `Composable` function(But instead you can use `Button` it will have more highlight ripple when we click)

Ex:

```
Column {
    TopAppBar(
        modifier = modifier,
        elevation = 0.dp,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
        title = {
            Text(text = "Jetpack Compose")
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = {  }) {
                Column {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally), tint = Red)
                    Text("Add")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Note: I am using `Column` inside `IconButton` because again `IconButton` content will be in `Box`.